# Incompatibility of solutions in an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a separable first-order ODE, we have the following form :

> $y' = g(x)h(y)$

It follows that $h(y) = 0$ poses a a set of solutions, potentially, to the ODE.

Now, understanding that concept, I came across the following example where I have to find the general solution to the following ODE given that $ y(1) = 1 $

> $ y' = \frac{(1+x)y}{x^2} $

Solving $ h(y) = 0$ gives the solution $y = 0$ however, this has been said to be 'incompatible' with $y(1) = 1$

Any further explanation that may help my understanding would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It says “potentially”... just try to integrate $$\frac{y’}{y}=\frac{1+x}{x^2}$$ wrt $x$ on both sides

Comment: @BAI I can integrate it, but this implication of incompatibility of solutions was posed prior to the worked solution, I was wondering what incompatibility meant

Comment: it simply means that there is no solution of the initial value problem for which $h(y)\equiv 0$, hence it gives you liberty to divide $y$ from both sides

Comment: @BAI I must admit, I am still not quite grasping it, sorry.

Comment: Well, if $y(x)=0$ for all $x$, then what is $y(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get too lost in the wording. The explanation is

$ y(x) = 0 $ implies $y(1) = 0$. However, the initial condition given is $y(1)=1$.

Therefore it can't be a solution. Simple as that.

Comment: Thank you very much, layman's terms were all it took for me to understand. Much appreciated